# topLayoutGuide applied after viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I have the issue that the `topLayoutGuide.length` in a `UIViewController` (from XIB) gets set after `viewWillAppear` and i don't know how to hook into the change of `topLayoutGuide.length` to initially set the contentOffset of a table view.

Code to modally present a `UIViewController` inside a `UINavigationController`:

```
let viewController = UIViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

My debugging output about the `topLayoutGuide.length`

```
Init view controller
-[UIViewController topLayoutGuide]: guide not available before the view controller's view is loaded
willMove toParentViewController  - top layout guide nan
Init navigation controller and pass view controller as root vc
Present navigation controller modally
viewDidLoad                      - top layout guide 0.0
viewWillAppear                   - top layout guide 0.0
viewWillLayoutSubviews           - top layout guide 64.0
viewDidLayoutSubviews            - top layout guide 64.0
viewWillLayoutSubviews           - top layout guide 64.0
viewDidLayoutSubviews            - top layout guide 64.0
viewDidAppear                    - top layout guide 64.0
didMove toParentViewController   - top layout guide 64.0
viewWillLayoutSubviews           - top layout guide 64.0
viewDidLayoutSubviews            - top layout guide 64.0
```

For now i use a bool flag in the view controller to set the contentoffset in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` only once, even though the method is called multiple times.

Any more elegant solution in mind?

Comment: Have you tried setting the layout anchors / layout constraints in `viewDidLoad`. Can you paste the code shows how you are setting the layout constraints / anchors ?

Comment: In my opinion the value doesn't matter as long as you are using auto layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation for the `topLayoutGuide`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621367-toplayoutguide) states explicitly:

> Query this property within your implementation of the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` method.

Judging from your own inspections the earliest point to obtain the `topLayoutGuide`'s actual length is inside the `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` method. However, I would not rely on that and do it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` as the docs suggest.

#### The reason why you cannot access the property earlier...

... is that the layout guides are objects that depend on the layout of any container view controllers. The views are laid out lazily when they are needed on screen. So when you add the `viewController` to the `navigationViewController` as its root view controller it's not laid out yet.

The layout happens when you present the `navigationController`. At that point the views of both view controllers are loaded (→ `viewDidLoad()`, `viewWillAppear()`) and then a layout pass is triggered. First, the `navigationViewController`'s view is laid out (layout flow: superview → subview). The navigation bar's frame is set to a height of 64 px. Now the `viewController`'s `topLayoutGuide` can be set. And finally the `viewController`'s view is laid out (→ `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`, `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`).

#### Conclusion:

The only way to do some *initial* layout tweaks that depend on the layout guide's length is the method you suggested yourself:

1. Have a boolean property in your view controller that you set to `true` initially:

   ```
   var isInitialLayoutPass: Bool = true
   ```
2. Inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` check for that property and only perform your initial layout when it's `true`:

   ```
   func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
       if isInitialLayoutPass {
           tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: topLayoutGuide.length)
       }
   }
   ```
3. Inside `viewDidAppear()`, set the property to `false` to indicate that the initial layout is done:

   ```
   override func viewDidAppear() {
       super.viewDidAppear()
       isInitialLayoutPass = false
   }
   ```

I know it still feels a little hacky but I'm afraid it's the only way to go (that I can think of) unless you want to use **key-value-observing (KVO)** which doesn't make it much neater in my opinion.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for the detailed explanation!

Comment: This is really great, thanks for answer and question also !